# Frasier: "Goose" and italian soccer team?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm watching the Frasier  season 2, episode 23 and there's line that goes:

> An Italian soccer team was sitting at the next table, Maris announced
> she was in the mood for a goose, and - perhaps inevitably - tragedy
> ensued.

Cue laugh track.

What's funny about the line?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03TaAZmCiF35mtQ667keQ-04uWGjQ%3A1598390052572&ei=JH9FX66jIojxrgSWtb0Q&q=%22An+Italian+soccer+team+was+sitting+at+the+next+table%2C+Maris%22+&oq=%22An+Italian+soccer+team+was+sitting+at+the+next+table%2C+Maris%22+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1DJPFj4f2CEggFoAHABeACAAXyIAXySAQMwLjGYAQOgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiuxa76orfrAhWIuIsKHZZaDwIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Answer (score 1):

It is tempting to think this is sexual innuendo based on a pun. She might order goose as  meal but, in the presence of so many young men, she is also alluding to being goosed, which involves her handling a lot of male sexual parts. The meaning goes back a long way. For example see https://www.rsc.org.uk/shakespeare/language/slang-and-sexual-language

Comment: Yeah, in the US being "goosed" means (or used to mean, 50 years ago) having someone poke your behind.

Comment: Thanks. I think that it now refers to even more imaginative and intimate contacts!

Comment: Hot Licks is right. It means to have one's bottom pinched [link](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Goosed). That's still its meaning today.

Comment: I think it has to do with national stereotypes, specifically Italian men. My sister and aunt (a 50 + year old Colonel in the Salvation Army) took a ride in a crowded tram in Rome around 1975. After they left the tram, my sister said she had been pinched several times. "So have I" said my aunt.